# Reset the style and colors on polygon in Google Earth Pro

Tags: google-earth

I was practicing using the polygon feature in Google Earth Pro following this guide here:

https://www.google.com/earth/outreach/learn/annotating-google-earth/#add-polygons-3

But now I want to reset the polygon to have no colors, just the red line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a polygon with an outline but no fill color, you just need to turn off the area fill:

- Go to the Edit window for the polygon
- Select the "Style,Color" tab
- Find the "Area" section
- Set the dropdown to "Outlined" (instead of "Filled+Outlined")
- Click "Ok" when you're done

[image]

That should remove the fill and leave the outline.

Alternatively you can set the Area Opacity to 0% for a see-through polygon (or something like 50% for a semi-transparent polygon).